# POP Random % of data from Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I have a dictionary('voltage') with multiple excel sheets as items in it. I want to extract 20% of the total number of sheets from the original dictionary and store them in a separate dictionary('sample'). I have written the following code.

```
data = pd.ExcelFile('filename.xlsx')

voltage = {}
for sheet in data.sheet_names:
        voltage[sheet] = pd.read_excel(data, sheet)

sample = dict(random.sample(voltage.items(), int(len(voltage) * 20 / 100)))
```

With the above code, I am able to get 20% of the total number of sheets but these sheets are not being removed from the original dictionary. I want to remove those randomly selected 20% sheets to be deleted from the original dictionary and to be stored in the new dictionary. Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? Sounds like you're going to end up with two identical dictionaries in the end. Also.. why are you not simply iterating over. `sample.keys()` and remove those element from the original dictionary?

Comment: I want to separate the data because I need to perform different operations on each set of data. Yea as I am new to python, i didnt know how to approach that...Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
for i in sample:
    del voltage[i]
```

This will remove all key-value items form your voltage dictionary, for all keys that our found in sample dictionary